# How to catch exceptions occur because of not conforming to NSCoding protocol in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

I am getting an exception from my published application which is:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19a8a170'`

and happens because of:

`@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *settings;`

`settingsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.settings];`

As this is a remote report, I cannot debug or find out the problematic object that was added to `NSMutableDictionary` without conforming to NSCoding protocol. Because of this reason, I am trying to find that object when an exception occurs. Remove it from the array and log it to learn what it is.

So, I use the following block:

```
NSData* settingsData = nil;

@try {
    settingsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.settings];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    for (id key in self.settings) {
         id value = [self.settings objectForKey:key];

        if(![value respondsToSelector:@selector(encodeWithCoder:)]){}
    }
}
@finally {

}
```

However, this exception is never catched on device and simulator. (tested on iOS7 and iOS8).

I don't want to test parameters if there are no exceptions every single time...
I don't want to test values while setting them to dictionary. (As already added ones will also create problem too)

Is there a way to catch this kind of exception?

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the exception while testing?

Comment: Yes, application just crashes to death, skipping catch block. I set a custom class without `encodeWithEncoder:` method on the array to test it.

Comment: Well, Objective-C exceptions are well-known to be unpredictable, and the use of try/catch is generally not recommended.  (Hence I've never attempted to use try/catch.)  It may be that you need to specifically catch `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Comment: As NSInvalidArgumentException is a string for the exception's name, I cannot directly catch it.. NSException should catch it too, but it doesn't :|

Comment: As I say, I've never studied how exceptions work, since the general consensus is that they don't.